# Create new Zendesk ticket with a new requester with user defined fields

Tags: javascript, json, zendesk

I`m creating Zendesk tickets on behalf of users (from mobile app) using this type of json request:

```
{"ticket": 
{"subject": "Subject",
"comment": { "body": complaintBody },
"requester": { "name": userInfo.name, "email": userInfo.email}}};
```

and everything works fine.
now what i want is to set a custom user_field at the time of creating a new ticket. is it possible? can not find information in zendesk docs... (

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reviewing the docs, it appears that the API endpoints (the [Ticket API](https://developer.zendesk.com/rest_api/docs/core/tickets) and the [Users API](https://developer.zendesk.com/rest_api/docs/core/users)) are separate, so I'm fairly sure you'd be unable to do this in one call.

But you could use a second call to the [Update User API](https://developer.zendesk.com/rest_api/docs/core/users#update-user) to update the custom user_field of the Zendesk user.